# Issue in popup using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Saw an example in bootstrap and try to execute it . I did the same what it is in getbootstrap.com but what i get is hidden form of below code.I think modal hide works well but it didnt show up that link is clicked.Please some one help me with this.
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
```

See [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/f9rTN/1/)

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=riHQAhk4mM

Comment: I assume you're including jQuery and bootstrap js files?

Comment: Create a [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net) please

Comment: sorry.i cant get you @SLoW

Comment: @RahilWazir to create in fiddle we have to add bootstrap-modal js link.But i tried and i cant find it.Please help on it.

Comment: @Pravin I don't know what you mean by that, but if you'll check the Bootstrap examples, you'll see that you have to have a link to the bootstrap and jQuery javascript files.  Check http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ under "Basic Template" and make sure you have all that.

Comment: i have added fiddle link..@SLoW @RahilWazir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look:
http://jsfiddle.net/QCH3q/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

in this example I added the jquery in **Frameworks & Extensions** that was missing. Is probably missing in your project.

Try Add jQuery: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js